# Return actual patched property value from patchcommand in RavenDb

Tags: c#, ravendb

A have a "Billing" class that's describe my finance account model in multithreading application. If i want to transfer money from one billing to another i make patchcommand that is increment one property and decrement another. What is the right way to return actual property value after patching without redundant Load-query?

#### Billing class

```
public class Billing
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
}
```

#### My patch method

```
public void TransferMoney(string billingSrc, string billingDst, decimal money)
    {
        _ctx.DatabaseCommands.Batch(new ICommandData[]
        {                
            new ScriptedPatchCommandData
            {
                Key = billingSrc,
                Patch = new ScriptedPatchRequest
                {
                    Script = @"this.Balance -= money;",
                    Values = {{"money", money}}
                }
            },
            new ScriptedPatchCommandData
            {
                Key = billingDst,
                Patch = new ScriptedPatchRequest
                {
                    Script = @"this.Balance += money;",
                    Values = {{"money", money}}
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `output()` method to send values back to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Since RavenDb v3, the set of predefined JavaScript functions available in `ScriptedPatchRequest` has method `output(message)`, which allows to debug your patch and print passed messages in the output. See documentation for [v3.0](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/Csharp/client-api/commands/patches/how-to-use-javascript-to-patch-your-documents), [v3.5](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/Csharp/client-api/commands/patches/how-to-use-javascript-to-patch-your-documents), [v4.0](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/Csharp/server/kb/javascript-engine).

See example below:

```
var balancePatch = dbSession.Advanced
    .DocumentStore
    .DatabaseCommands
    .Patch(
        billingDst /* document ID */,
        new ScriptedPatchRequest
        {
            Script = @"this.Balance += money; output(this.Balance);",
            Values = {{"money", money}}
        });

// Reading the debug output
var balance = balancePatch["Debug"].Values().First().Value<decimal>();
```